# UISearchController dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I see the `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` is now deprecated in iOS SDK 12. What is the replacement of this attribute?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618660-dimsbackgroundduringpresentation)  Use the

```
obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation
```

property instead.